# I am getting error while importing files on Remix IDE from GitHub

Tags: solidity, remix, error, import

Error: not found https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol. I am getting this error while importing the files from OpenZepplin GitHub repository. I even went through the official documentation of the Remix IDE for importing files but even that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a simple ERC20 token in Remix IDE using the default OpenZeppelin imports:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") ERC20Permit("MyToken") {}
}
```

And here's the same example using imports off the OpenZeppelin repo imports:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") ERC20Permit("MyToken") {}
}
```